# TypeError: this.$__setSchema is not a function

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert data into mongodb at [mongodb cloud](https://cloud.mongodb.com/). But while running the code i am getting error like TypeError: this.$__setSchema is not a function.

[image]

```
//Function Called

this.$__setSchema(_schema);

//Function Definition

Document.prototype.$__setSchema = function(schema) {

    schema.plugin(idGetter, { deduplicate: true });
    compile(schema.tree, this, undefined, schema.options);

    // Apply default getters if virtual doesn't have any (gh-6262)
    for (const key of Object.keys(schema.virtuals)) {
        schema.virtuals[key]._applyDefaultGetters();
    }
    if (schema.path('schema') == null) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }
    this.$__schema = schema;
    this[documentSchemaSymbol] = schema;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

mongoose.Model  ✘

mongoose.model  ✔

You need to change the first letter of Model to small letter. if you use the capital letter and then you get this ("TypeError: this.$__setSchema is not a function") error.

Comment: Thank you. This works